# Ubuntu extract zip package is flattened, sub-folders are missing

Tags: archive, zip, file-roller

I zipped a folder in Windows. The folder contains files and sub-folders.

I copied and extracted the zipped file to two Ubuntu machines: Ubuntu-A and Ubuntu-B. (I extracted them exactly the same way.)

[image]

In Ubuntu-A the extracted output follows the same original folder structure of the original source in Windows. However, with Ubuntu-B the extracted output is flattened. All the subfolders are gone and instead all the files are extracted together inside just one folder.

I need Ubuntu-B to extract like Ubuntu-A. I'm not sure why they behave differently. Both machines are using built-in Archive Manager, that uses File Roller.

Answer (score 0):

Windows zipped the package using Windows path separators '\'. Ubuntu A (v19) seemed to be fine with it. But didn't work with Ubuntu B (v18). I got around the problem using 7zip instead of the default Windows zip.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `aunpack` utility available in the `atool` package. It generally does the right thing in situations like this.

From the man page description:

> aunpack  extracts  files  from an archive. Often one wants to extract
>   all files in an archive to a single subdirectory.  However, some
>   archives contain multiple files in their root directories. The aunpack
>   program overcomes this problem by first extracting files to a unique
>   (temporary) directory, and then moving its contents back if possible.
>   This also prevents local files from being overwritten by mistake.